# how does timepiece.inostudio.de clock font works?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts, ligature

checkout [timepiece.inostudio.de](http://timepiece.inostudio.de/)

How does the font translate "03:35:40" to a symbol? I tried this with http://icomoon.io/ but doesn't seem to be possible with ligatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Font Lab Studio is the solution